# Getting an error while running following code

Tags: c, arrays

I wrote a code but I don't know why it does not work and print"beterek" .
also it doesn't go through my while loop and doesn't call my cam func...
please help...
the following code is one part of my code:

```
int main()
        {
        int a[100], b[100], diff=0, m=0, n=0, temp[100], s=0,z,max=0;
        printf("Enter binary number 1: ");
        scanf("%d", &a[100]);
        printf("Enter binary number 2: ");
        scanf("%d", &b[100]);
        while(a!='\0')
                m++;
        while(b!='\0')
                n++;
        if(m>n)
        {
                printf("beterek");
                max = m;
                diff = m - n;
                for(s=0; s<=diff; s++)
                        temp[s] = 0;

                for(z=s; z<=n; z++)
                        temp[s] = b[s];
        cal(a,temp);
        }
        else
        {
        printf("beterek");
                max = n;
                diff = n - m;
                for(s=0; s<=diff; s++)
                        temp[s] = 0;

                for(z=s; z<=m; z++)
                        temp[s] = a[s];
        cal(b, temp);
        }
        }
```

Comment: What do you think `while(a!='\0') m++;` would do?

Comment: So...
you think sizeof would do on my code friend?

Comment: a and b are integer arrays. Why check for `\0`? `\0` terminates strings aka char arrays not int arrays!

Comment: @hhachem how can I do that ?

Comment: get the input as string using `fread`, then use `scanf` in a loop until you reach the end of the string that you read. This way you automatically calculate the length of `a` and `b`

Comment: I meant `fgets` not `fread`check the code in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use fgets to read the input string till you a reach a newline character (that means till the user hits enter). Then convert each character to int.

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main()
            {
            int a[100], b[100], diff=0, m=0, n=0, temp[100], s=0,z,max=0;
            int iIndex=0;
            char cString[100];
            int i=0;
            char* cpString=NULL;
            memset(&cString,0,100);
            printf("Enter binary number 1: ");
            //scanf("%s",cString);
            fgets(cString,sizeof(cString),stdin);
            cpString=cString;
            while(*cpString!='\n'){
                a[iIndex]=*cpString-'0'; // this converts char to int
                cpString++;
                iIndex++;
            }
            printf("Count of elements in a : %d\n", iIndex);
            for (i=0;i<iIndex;i++){
                printf("%d\n",a[i]);
            }
            return 0;
            }
```

Output:

```
Enter binary number 1: 1101010
Count of elements in a : 7
1
1
0
1
0
1
0
```

Just make sure you check wether the input number is a valid binary number!

Comment: now!!! If I try two add to binary file like this, is it possible?I have binary 1 and binary 2 now..I'm trying to do: bin1 + bin2...Is it possible?

Comment: well. Everything is possible. Buf if you wanted to add them together, then why did you want to store each bit seperately? Anyway you could do:
`int number=0;int temp=0;
for (i=0;i<lengthofa;i++){ 
temp=a[i]<<(lengthofa-i);
number+=temp;
}`
this converts the array to an integer

Comment: you know because of carry ...when you add two binaries you face to carries...each bit should add together..thank you..I try what you said.. :)

Comment: `a[i]<<(lengthofa-i-1)`, just make sure you calculate the lengthofa correctly. check here for an example: http://ideone.com/28vEjo